# creating a database for a website and mobile app

Tags: android, mysql, database, mobile

I want to create a database so both my website and mobile app could draw info from there.
I know how to execute queries with a website, but I have little to none experience with mobile applications.
I heard I can't just use any form of database(mysql, mongodb) because they are not compatible or something.
so how do I create my database so it will be compatible with android iOS and PC.
A few guidelines to get me started would be great :)

Comment: Generally your apps/site would both call the same web service. A web service returns data in xml so it can be read by any device

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to build an API to handle interaction between your mobile applications and your database, in much the same way your website communicates with your database. The primary difference will be that you will be returning JSON/XML to your apps, rather than displaying HTML to a user.

I thoroughly recommend JSON over XML as it is not as verbose and data usage will drop dramatically. However, if you're data structures are quite detailed / complex, go with XML.

To get started with building an API I'll recommend [Slim PHP](http://www.slimframework.com/). You'll probably want some form of ORM also, for which I highly recommend [idiorm/paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/)

The documentation for both of these frameworks is great, so have a dig around.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database with MySQL and draw info from your site with mysql queries. As for your mobile app, you can use some php pages and JSON Parser to draw data from the database. See [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

As you say android doesn't support external databases such as MySQL. The easiest thing to do would be to create a MySQL Database that your website and android app can access.

The website would access the MySQL database as normal but the android app instead posts data such as variables to a PHP script, the PHP script can then get the retrieved data and perform the mysql queryies and `json_encode` the output and print the encoded data. The android app would then receive the outputted json format and the android app can then decode the json and process the data accordingly.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database has some tutorials on how this can be done

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **Service - Oriented Architecture**.

You may use REST API methodology for creating interfaces.

See this example 
[www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/)